# Website tabs that fully function (with images)

Tags: java, html, css

As a starter project, I aimed to design a website with most simple structures needed. I wanted to create tabs, that were fully functional upon being clicked.

I wanted it to look something like this: ([   ] = Tab)

[(IMG)    (TEXT)    ][(IMG)    (TEXT)    ][(IMG)    (TEXT)    ]

I could do something like this code wise:

```
<ul>
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

But how could I make this horizontal rather than vertical?

And how could I make these do special things such as;

- actually appear as tabs (in rectangles)
- add color changes upon being hovered over and click
- and deter which tab they are currently on.

(The over all goal of this is to make the different tabs trigger different images)

Comment: www.codecademy.com has a pretty good tutorial with an inbrowser editor that will walk you through HTML CSS JS and Jquery.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll make sure to check it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

i really recommend use links at navigation:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

soo your css code should look like this:
you can add css rule:

```
ul li { float: left; }
```

yo make them rectangles:

```
ul li a {
background-color: red;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid black; }
```

to add some functionality:

```
ul li a:hover, ul li a:focus, ul li a:visited, ul li a:active {
background-color: white; }
```

to deter which tab they currently i cannot answer right now.. because it depends which TVS or framework system you gonna use and how you gonna use your page pagination